# Beginner - load sqlite data as global variable

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

Database.java

```
public class Data extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static String week, classes, title, mat, it, comp, que;
```

///more common codes like create, drop database

```
 public String[] getAllIAI(){

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_IAI + "WHERE KEY_week =" +LessonPlanner.itemWeek+ "AND KEY_class=" +LessonPlanner.itemClass ;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor3 = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    String[] data = null;
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            title=cursor.getString(3);
            mat=cursor.getString(4);
            it=cursor.getString(5);
       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return data;
}
```

Recomend.Java

Declared

```
TextView  title, mat, IT;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recomend);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    mat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.materialText);
    IT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.instTText);

    title.setText(Data.title);
    mat.setText(Data.mat);
    IT.setText(Data.it);
```

I think that code is wrong somewhere because the Textview (Multiline Text) did not show any thing. 
can anyone point out my mistake? I totally new to Eclipse.

Comment: Do you know how to set breakpoints and trace through your code? I would recommend doing that.  Also, You can use Log.v or Log.d to print things out to the console, and you can see what is reallly happening.

Comment: I don't know. I totally new and I working this apps for my assignment. The app actually working fine. Just that no data show in multiline text.

Comment: You should look up on how to set and use breakpoints, and on how to print out log statements.  You will be a pretty dangerous programmer if you can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code, first, the array "data" you return is always null, so of course you cannot get anything from it.

Second, if you plan to get several results from the database, you should declare a list and add the objets you got from the DB in it, currently your loop is totally useless, you instantiate variables that you never use...

Here is an example showing how to get a List from the DB, but you could also get a Cursor, an Array or whatever you need:

```
// Getting All Categories By ID
    public List<Category> getCategoriesList() {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT " + CATEGORY_ID + ", " + CATEGORY_NAME + " FROM " + CATEGORY_TABLE + " ORDER BY " + CATEGORY_ID + " ASC";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); 

        List<Category> categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category>();

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Category category = new Category(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), false);
                categoriesList.add(category);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return categoriesList;
    }
```

NOTE: in this example I get several rows from the DB, if you want to get only one row, just remove the loop do-while and return the object directly.

Comment: what should I change so it actually get the data from sqlite and store in the variable?

Comment: The app I doing is acutally get 1 row of data based of the "choices" they choose [the Where condition]. only 1 row and multiple column. each data in the column will display in multiline text in xml.